# Accessing remote SQL Server database using Windows authenticated impersonated local account

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, windows, authentication

Sorry for the long title...

Here is the situation - 2 machines:

1. IIS 7.5/App server Windows 2008
2. SQL Server 2008

The SQL Server machine has a **local** account `SpecialUser1`. This account is used as login account in SQL Server itself and has full access to the database.

The IIS machine has an identical **local** account `SpecialUser1`.

Web application is setup using Windows Authentication + ASP.NET impersonation with that `SpecialUser1` defined in **identity** tag of `web.config`.

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="SpecialUser1" password="SpecialPassword" />
```

And it's using Integrated Security access to the SQL Server, defined in a connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ConnectionString1" 
        connectionString="Data Source=SQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=DB1;Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Will the web application be able to get access to the SQL Server's database using that impersonated account? Meaning - are these 2 identical accounts mapped to grant access to the database ?

I relied on the information from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z(v=vs.100).aspx

and here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292114(v=vs.71).aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I came across your question while researching windows impersonation, which has changed in MVC5. One thing that struck me is if you only have one user for accessing the database then I don't think you really need impersonation. You could just put the username/password in the connection string.

Clearly you might have other things going on that you haven't mentioned that rules this out. However, the simple answers are often the best so I thought I would add this.

PS. Be warned that windows impersonation seems to have changed in MVC5. See this [question](http://forums.asp.net/t/1961337.aspx?Asp+Net+MVC+5+how+to+impersonate+user+on+IIS) the asp.net forum for more information. I'm still researching how to do this.